# Embedded C utilizing a flag from a complex structure

Tags: c, embedded, structure, instance

In a source file [inv_mpu.c](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IDhPfvlmOGV8HhAZx8WBUMZ-YNYk0SR9/view?usp=sharing) there is a structure definition `gyro_state_s` and a file scope variable declaration:

```
static struct gyro_state_s st = {
    .reg = &reg,
    .hw = &hw,
    .test = &test
};
```

Nested in this structure is a member `st.chip_cfg.bypass_mode` that I wish to access from withing another file.

Question: How to read the state of this flag `st.chip_cfg.bypass_mode` within another file?

I have tried `extern struct gyro_State_s st ;`, but this remains unrecognized when I test it in `if(!st.chip_cfg.bypass_mode)`.

Comment: Off-site links to your code makes for a poor question.  Questions last indefinitely on SO; can you say the same for your externally served file?  If you later take that file down or it otherwise becomes unavailable, the question will no longer make much sense.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Attempting to expose *all of `st`* and its definition just to access this one flag is a bad design and should be avoided.  [Globals are always bad](https://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/break-points/4025723/A-pox-on-globals), and in this case you would be unnecessarily making all the internals of `st` visible to the entire program.

inv_mpu.c already has a function `mpu_set_bypass()` which is called before it is used, so must have a prototype somewhere, most likely in the existing header inv_mpu.h.  The simplest, safest and most in-keeping with the existing code style solution would be to add a "*getter*" accessor counter-part `mpu_get_bypass()`.

In inv_mpu.c you might add:

```
unsigned char mpu_get_bypass( void )
{
    return st.chip_cfg.bypass_mode ;
}
```

The add the prototype declaration to inv_mpu.h thus:

```
unsigned char mpu_get_bypass( void ) ;
```

Then in the accessing source file, you `#include "inv_mpu.h"`, then call the getter, thus for example:

```
if( !mpu_get_bypass() ) ...
```

Answer (score -2):

Put the structure in a shared header that is included in both files.

extern means: 'this is defined/instantiated elsewhere'

Since a structure on it's down doesn't compile to any physical code (an instance of a structure does, the structure itself just describes how to create an instance of it) you just need to define the same structure in both files, this is best done by putting the structure in a shared header then including the header in both of the files you need the structure in.

Comment: Whilst that is the way you would correctly do what Cy is attempting and failing to do, it is not a solution I'd encourage. Globals - especially large and complex globals [should be avoided](https://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/break-points/4025723/A-pox-on-globals)

Comment: I never said use a global, I told him to put the structure in the header which is perfectly acceptable because it doesn't generate any actual code on it's own.

Then I told him what an extern actually is because he's not using it correctly.

A getter/setter would work but that's really dumb for a single member of the structure, especially when you're embedded and may be limited for space.

Comment: In the question he is attempting to get global access to `struct gyro_State_s st`, and your answer tells him how to do that.  An accessor is exactly appropriate when you want access to a single member and _nothing else_.   Did you follow my link in the previous comment?  If you think globals are acceptable and an accessor "really dumb", I think you are in the minority within the _profession_. As it happens if you look at the existing code you will see that there is already an 'setter' accessor for that member, a 'getter' is therefore entirely appropriate regardless.

Comment: global access to the structure/member does NOT mean his instance of the structure is in global scope, or even globally defined. Global access simply means that wherever his instance is defined (global or not) he can still access the member.

A getter/setter for ONE member is brainbroken, if you're going the route of getter/setters then you should make getter/setters for all the members of the huge structure, which again is brainbroken especially in an embedded environment where space may be limited and you're wasting it writing identical getter/setter functions for every single member.

Comment: This is no longer an appropriate discussion for comments.  Readers should take it or leave it, and you need not defend your solution - it was not an attack on your answer, merely advice (and I did not down-vote).  Your answer does not mention global data, but in the question Cy is attempting to make `st` global, and you assisted in this ill advised solution.  I have much to say on your opinion in comment, but it is irrelevant to the question in hand - you see out of touch with the fundamental principles of minimal coupling, maximal cohesion, access control and data hiding - not my problem..

Comment: Apologies I didn't realize he actually had a global instance already, I thought he had some instance 'st' that he wanted to access from another file, and I didn't bother reading his externally linked source code so it seemed strange to create a getter for a single variable.

I am realizing now that the instance was global and static, in which case a getter would be the perfect solution, please excuse my lazy answer and ignorant comments.

And of course like you mentioned a getter will entirely decouple the calling code from the structure definition.